# How to specify 'Unlimited' for a value for that is defined by datatype duration?

Tags: xml, xsd, duration

I have the the grammar of a xml element defined by

```
<xsd:element name="valid" type="xsd:duration"/>
```

but in the xml I want to specify an infinite duration. How can i specify infinite duration?

I checked http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-2-20010502/#duration but I could not find a way to specify unlimited duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must [define the maximum](http://www.java2s.com/Code/XML/XML-Schema/xsmaxInclusivedefinesamaximumvaluethatcanbereachedbasedonxsduration.htm) for your application. XSLT engines may support different maximums, but it is up to you to define it using `maxInclusive`.

```
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:duration">
  <xsd:maxInclusive value="P3M" />
</xsd:restriction>
```

Comment: oh okay. I will specify a maximum for my own. and use this to declare it.

Answer (score 0):

what is this XML for? Do you need it for a third party software? Or is it only for your own data? If it is the latter, I suggest you use a convention. For example :

```
P0D              0 = unlimited
P9999Y           a very large duration
-P1D             some negative duration
```

etc.

If it is for communication between another system, define a maximum and specifying a duration beyond that maximum would be another idea.

Comment: Its for my own data. But is this part of any xml specification standard? I don't want to deviate from a standard if there is some existing, if not, yes I will define a standard for my use. Thanks!

Comment: If it is not defined (and even if it is, actually), you may specify any standard. A standard is a standard, and you may specify anything as you wish, as long as it's standard, and coherent across your entire application :) ...and don't forget to document your standards!!

Comment: Yep, definitely I can use a standard across my application... I was just wondering there is some xml standard for it. As you had mentioned, seems like there is none, so I will create one for mine :)))